# Angular Material Data table search Filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-filters

I am trying to apply the a dynamic angular filter to the md data table to search through the data on the grid. however it doesn't seem to be working here is a small exapmple of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
    <md-input-container>
      <label> Search Table </label>
       <input  ng-model="filter.search"> 
    </md-input-container>

  <tr md-row md-select="dessert" md-auto-select ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit">
```

Comment: Please add the controller code.

Comment: I'm using this code pen for the md-data-table: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbLaMb
all I'm adding is a search input field to try an filter the data

Comment: http://codepen.io/next1/pen/OpyQXW it is working

Comment: Thanks! the only thing actually is, I was trying to configure it to work like this example with this table: https://datatables.net/  
if you type part of a word from one column press space, then type part of another word from another column it filters accordingly. Do you know if this is possible with the md data table or is it just a feature with that particular table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you showed, I am adding custom filter which will do as described by you.

Here is the custom filter.

```
$scope.filters = [];
$scope.$watch('filter.search', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if(newValue != undefined){
  $scope.filters = newValue.split(" ");
 }
})

$scope.searachData = {};

$scope.customSearch = function(item) {
$scope.searachData.status = true;

angular.forEach($scope.filters, function(value1, key) {
  $scope.searachData.tempStatus = false;
  angular.forEach(item, function(value2, key) {
    var dataType = typeof(value2);

    if(dataType == "string" && (!value2.includes('object'))){
      if(value2.toLowerCase().includes(value1)){
        $scope.searachData.tempStatus = true;
      }
    }else if(dataType == "object"){
      var num = value2.value.toString();
      if(num.includes(value1)){
        $scope.searachData.tempStatus = true;
      }
    }
  });
          $scope.searachData.status = $scope.searachData.status & $scope.searachData.tempStatus;
});

return $scope.searachData.status;
};
```

Here is the working [Example](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/OpyQXW).

Comment: Thanks! I will try an follow this example

Comment: It works fine when my data is hard coded. but when I get it from a service it seems to throw a lot of console errors. but I am trying to debug it now

Comment: Because of your object structure, you might get some errors. Please provide your object structure and I'll do necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks it's something like:

   `object[
 { name: john Adams,
   weight: 178,
   Age:     27
   sport:  basketball
 },

        { name: Michael Johnson,
   weight: 188,
   Age:     22
   sport:  Football
 },
 { name: Steven Richards
   weight: 177,
   Age:     21
   sport:  Baseball
 }
]`

Comment: The error the console is giving is Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: it it possible to ignore certain properties with this filter. for example if I wanted to ignore age and sport and only filter on name and weight.